# Unable to invoke symfony console command via "aws lambda invoke"

Tags: symfony, aws-lambda, aws-cdk, symfony-console, bref

I'm trying to run symfony "bin/console" command like described in [documentation](https://bref.sh/docs/runtimes/console.html#usage-without-serverless-framework).

Running command

```bash
aws lambda invoke \
    --function-name PhpCliLambdaName \
    --region us-east-1 \
    --cli-binary-format raw-in-base64-out \
    --payload '"d:s:u --dump-sql"' \
    response.json
```

returns

```json
{
    "StatusCode": 200,
    "FunctionError": "Unhandled",
    "ExecutedVersion": "$LATEST"
}
```

and logs this

```
{
    "errorType": "TypeError",
    "errorMessage": "Bref\\Runtime\\FileHandlerLocator::{closure}(): Argument #1 ($context) must be of type array, string given, called in /var/task/vendor/bref/bref/src/Runtime/Invoker.php on line 29",
    "stack": [
        "#0 /var/task/vendor/bref/bref/src/Runtime/Invoker.php(29): Bref\\Runtime\\FileHandlerLocator->{closure}('d:s:u --dump-sq...', Object(Bref\\Context\\Context))",
        "#1 /var/task/vendor/bref/bref/src/Runtime/LambdaRuntime.php(89): Bref\\Runtime\\Invoker->invoke(Object(Closure), 'd:s:u --dump-sq...', Object(Bref\\Context\\Context))",
        "#2 /var/task/vendor/bref/bref/src/FunctionRuntime/Main.php(37): Bref\\Runtime\\LambdaRuntime->processNextEvent(Object(Closure))",
        "#3 /opt/bref/bootstrap.php(17): Bref\\FunctionRuntime\\Main::run()",
        "#4 {main}"
    ]
}
```

*CDK*

package.json

```json
"@bref.sh/constructs": "^1.0.0",
```

brefStack.ts

```
this.fpm = new PhpFpmFunction(this, 'PhpFpm', {
  code,
  handler: 'public/index.php',
  timeout: Duration.seconds(20),
  ...lambdaProps,
});

this.cli = new ConsoleFunction(this, 'PhpCli', {
  code,
  handler: 'bin/console',
  timeout: Duration.seconds(120),
  ...lambdaProps, // contains architecture, environment, role, securityGroups, vpc and vpcSubnets
});
```

*Symfony - code*

composer.json (symfony 6.3)

```json
"bref/bref": "^2.0",
"bref/symfony-bridge": "0.2.1",
"symfony/runtime": "6.3.*"
```

bin/console

```php
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

use App\Kernel;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application;

if (!is_file(dirname(__DIR__).'/vendor/autoload_runtime.php')) {
    throw new LogicException('Symfony Runtime is missing. Try running "composer require symfony/runtime".');
}

require_once dirname(__DIR__).'/vendor/autoload_runtime.php';

return function (array $context) {
    $kernel = new Kernel($context['APP_ENV'], (bool) $context['APP_DEBUG']);

    return new Application($kernel);
};
```

I've already tried to send payload as json object with APP_ENV, APP_DEBUG, but in this case I'm not able to figure out how should I provide command.
Changing $context to string and creating Kernel with $_SERVER doesn't help either.

I was able to execute command with modified `bin/console` and payload `{"command":"d:s:u", "--force": true}`, but this time lambda could not return response and timed out (but schema did update).

```php
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

use App\Kernel;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application;

if (!is_file(dirname(__DIR__).'/vendor/autoload_runtime.php')) {
    throw new LogicException('Symfony Runtime is missing. Try running "composer require symfony/runtime".');
}

require_once dirname(__DIR__).'/vendor/autoload_runtime.php';

return function (array $context) {
    $kernel = new Kernel($_SERVER['APP_ENV'], (bool) $_SERVER['APP_DEBUG']);

    $application = new Application($kernel);

    $input = new Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput($context);
    $output = new Symfony\Component\Console\Output\BufferedOutput();

    $application->run($input, $output);

    return new Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response($output->fetch());
};
```

Looking at [ConsoleRuntime](https://github.com/brefphp/bref/blob/master/src/ConsoleRuntime/Main.php) I'm clearly missing "event". But how can I provide it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of `@bref.sh/constructs` version `1.0.1` this issue should be resolved.

The problem was in `@aws-cdk/aws-lambda:recognizeVersionProps` flag set to true inside of `cdk.json`.
This flag might change order in which lambda layers are created.

If you encounter similar issue try to check if layers of your lambda are in correct order as they can override each other.